# How to get static image from google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I use google maps api for iOS. I want to get static image of special city and paste it in UIImageView. How can I make it?

Comment: Here is link for Objecive c, you can try this

Comment: you may find something here then.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?hl=en

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the reply of @Ankit is right, but @Alexsander asked in Swift, so :

```
var staticMapUrl: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue|\(self.staticData.latitude),\(self.staticData.longitude)&\("zoom=13&size=\(2 * Int(mapFrame.size.width))*\(2 * Int(mapFrame.size.height))")&sensor=true"
var mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))!
var image: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithData(NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(mapUrl))
var mapImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: mapFrame)
```

> for swift 4

```
let staticMapUrl: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=\(self.finalLatitude),\(self.finalLongitude)&\("zoom=15&size=\(2 * Int(imgViewMap.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(imgViewMap.frame.size.height))")&sensor=true"

let mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl)!
self.imgViewMap.sd_setImage(with: mapUrl as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "palceholder"))
```

Comment: @maroc how to calculate the zoom :(

Comment: You are missing 'x' sign between size params: size=100x100

Comment: I tried this way to open my link but app got crashed on  `let mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl)!`   this. Can you please let me know why this happened.

Comment: As documented in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#key-and-signature-parameters, you need to add an google maps API Key, maybe it wasn't a requirement at the time

Answer (score 5):

```
    NSString *staticMapUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue|%@,%@&%@&sensor=true",self.staticData.latitude, self.staticData.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zoom=13&size=%dx%d",2*(int)mapFrame.size.width, 2*(int)mapFrame.size.height]];
    NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[staticMapUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl]];

    UIImageView *mapImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:mapFrame];
```

This should help.

Comment: I know only city name

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift 3:

```
let lat = ..
let long = ..

let staticMapUrl: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|\(lat),\(long)&\("zoom=13&size=\(2 * Int(cell.imgAddress.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(cell.imgAddress.frame.size.height))")&sensor=true"

let url = URL(string: staticMapUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)

do {
    let data = try NSData(contentsOf: url!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
    cell.imgAddress.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
} catch {
    cell.imgAddress.image = UIImage()
}
```

Comment: how to calculate zoom :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Note you have to get API key from [Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?__utma=102347093.264945340.1510558269.1543386203.1543386203.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1543386203&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1543386203.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=228728860&_ga=2.161461245.1338207626.1543300579-264945340.1510558269#get-started)

```
let API_Key = //Your API Key.
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=\(2 * Int(imgBanner.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(imgBanner.frame.size.height))&maptype=roadmap&key=\(API_Key)"
let mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl)!
self.imgBanner.sd_setImage(with: mapUrl as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "palceholder"))
```

Always check the link in browser to view whether it is working fine or not means in the image is visible or not.