# How to get static image from google maps in iOS in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I use google maps api for iOS. I want to get static image of map, i have latitude and longitude  and want to paste it in UIImageView. How can I make it in swift 3.0?

Comment: What do you mean "I want to get static image and use it in UIImageView." You mean you want to capture a screen-shot of the map view as it's displayed?

Comment: yes, i want to capture a screen-shot of the map view as it's displayed

Comment: It appears you created this question solely to farm reputation in addition to the answer you wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851795/how-to-get-static-image-from-google-maps-in-ios/40640731#40640731). That's not how the system is supposed to work; the answer in the other question is fine, this here is somewhat more dubious

Comment: Pekka, i was looking for answer in swift 3 and all previous answer is in swift 2 or objective C, that's why i raised this question, so after i got answer , i shared this answer in both question because i was not allowed to delete my question. wherever, i have marked it as duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 3

```
        let Width = 100
        let Height = 200

        let mapImageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
        let latlong = "18.495651759752, 73.809987567365"

        let mapUrl  = mapImageUrl + latlong

        let size = "&size=" +  "\(Int(Width))" + "x" +  "\(Int(Height))"
        let positionOnMap = "&markers=size:mid|color:red|" + latlong
        let staticImageUrl = mapUrl + size + positionOnMap

        if let urlStr : NSString = staticImageUrl.addingPercentEscapes(using:String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSString{
            // setImageFromURL 
       }
```

Comment: I need to set the below URL to imageview. But unable to set. 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&maptype=roadmap&path=color:0x000000%7Cweight:10%7Cenc:u~kzDw}fsMsPxMeHvFkDnC}@r@a@bDdCrElJtQtB`E|@`BeG|EjBpDjA|BqAhA{CjCj@bA&markers=color:green%7Clabel:P%7C30.7046,76.7179&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C30.707998,76.703069&key=AIzaSyDdchM7apzEter6yaWfyQG-dF6AORh34MA&size=400x150`

Answer (score 1):

you can try with that :

```
myMap.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

It will return a UIView that you can use however you want