# not able to set map as image in uiimageview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, maps

```
let staticURL : String = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/London,+UK/@51.528308,-0.3817765,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583\("zoom=15&size=\(2 * Int(imgForMap.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(imgForMap.frame.size.height))")&sensor=true"
let mapURL = URL(string: staticURL)!
self.imgForMap.sd_setAnimationImages(with: [mapURL as URL])
```

Above code is not working.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34905999/10259204) answer!

Comment: @Dimple I have tried it already but it is not working for me.

Comment: What you mean by it's not working? Can you be more specific like what line of code is not working and what error you are getting?

Comment: The url is not same of yours with the shared answer. Please check proper url

Comment: @Dimple I tried it and it gave this error ->  finished with error - code: -1022

Comment: can you print `staticURL` and share it?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Static URL -> https://www.google.com/maps/place/London,+UK/@51.528308,-0.3817765,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583zoom=15&size=400x400&sensor=true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get static image from google maps in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851795/how-to-get-static-image-from-google-maps-in-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Note you have to get API key from [Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?__utma=102347093.264945340.1510558269.1543386203.1543386203.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1543386203&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1543386203.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)%7Cutmccn=(direct)%7Cutmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=228728860&_ga=2.161461245.1338207626.1543300579-264945340.1510558269#get-started)

```
let API_Key = //Your API Key.
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=\(2 * Int(imgBanner.frame.size.width))x\(2 * Int(imgBanner.frame.size.height))&maptype=roadmap&key=\(API_Key)"
let mapUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: staticMapUrl)!
self.imgBanner.sd_setImage(with: mapUrl as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "palceholder"))
```

Always check the link in browser to view whether it is working fine or not means the image is showing correctly without any `Map error: g.co/staticmaperror`. If you find any `staticmaperror`, please visit [map-static-error-messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/error-messages).

Sample image:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=AIzaSyAJgFSXOEIqBWIZ2vUcngjpX5fBBFmX6t0

Comment: I have a URL. but not visible on imageview. It is working fine on browser. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&maptype=roadmap&path=color:0x000000%7Cweight:10%7Cenc:u~kzDw}fsMsPxMeHvFkDnC}@r@a@bDdCrElJtQtB`E|@`BeG|EjBpDjA|BqAhA{CjCj@bA&markers=color:green%7Clabel:P%7C30.7046,76.7179&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C30.707998,76.703069&key=AIzaSyDdchM7apzEter6yaWfyQG-dF6AORh34MA&size=400x150`

Comment: Can u please share your code for how you are downloading image data and showing image on UIImageView?

Comment: I am using below code:
`let newString = imageurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!`
After that i am converting this string into url and showing that url on imageview with the help of `SDWebImage`

Comment: There is an issue with the url which you have shared. It is work fine when I tried `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&maptype=roadmap&path=color:0x000000|weight:10|enc:u~kzDw}fsMsPxMeHvFkDnC}@r@a@bDdCrElJtQtBE|@BeG|EjBpDjA|BqAhA{CjCj@bA&markers=color:green|label:P|30.7046,76.7179&markers=color:red|label:D|30.707998,76.703069&key=AIzaSyDdchM7apzEter6yaWfyQG-dF6AORh34MA&size=400x150`

Comment: If you see both the url will work on Browser but if i tried it to set on UIImageView id show something weird.